# How to represent a character <char> using regular expression in lex?

Tags: lex

How to represent a character  using regular expression in lex ?
According to my specifications a char class is :

"A char is any printable ASCII character (ASCII values between decimal value 32 and 126, or octal 40 and 176) other than quote ("), single quote (’), or backslash (\), plus the 2-character sequences "\"" to denote quote, "\'" to denote single quote, "\\" to denote backslash, "\t" to denote a literal tab, or "\n" to denote newline."

So how can I represent it using regular expression in lex?

Comment: Have you looked at the [manual](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns)

Answer (score 1):

You can have this in the rule section (the values here are octal..)

When you try to pass these values via keyboard eg: `DEL -> ^[[3~`(combinations of characters stored in the `STDIN`) thus use `yyin=(FILE *)fopen(filename,mode);`

```
%%
[\00-\37\42\47\134\t\n] ;//this omits the not required inputs
\177 return;//just for a exit key
. {action(s)}
%%
```

or

```
%%
[\00-\37\42\47\134\t\n]|\177 ;//omits inputs that are not to be considered
. {required action(s)}
%%
```

refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ae5bf541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx